# How to apply Celery signals to a group of tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

I want to do some processing before and after a group of tasks is run. I know I can connect a single task to [task_prerun](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.4/userguide/signals.html#task-prerun) and [task_postrun](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.4/userguide/signals.html#task-postrun) signals, but I'm using [task.chunks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.4/userguide/canvas.html#chunks) and need to apply the `task_prerun` signal once before running the first task, and the `task_postrun` signal once after finishing the last task with the last chunk. Is there any way I can do this, or any alternative method to achieve the same goal?